# Глагол, образованный от слова "интервенция"

Tags: глаголы

Интервировать? Интервицировать?
Не нашёл примеров в источниках.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В источниках нашлось вот что.
[**интервени́ровать**](https://slovaronline.com/browse/b8c4f2d1-6a8a-3d3f-a417-f22c6f0ec4c7/%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)

Исторический словарь галлицизмов русского языка:
от лат. *intervenire* — вмешиваться, вступаться. *Производить интервенцию.* Интервенировать страну. БАС-1.

Толковый словарь Ушакова:
сов. и несов. (книжн.). Произвести (производить) интервенцию.

Слово есть в орфографическом словаре русского языка (посмотрела печатный вариант 1957 года — имеется); в универсальном русско-польском словаре — *interweniować*; в русско-белорусском словаре — *інтэрвеніраваць*; в русско-английском юридическом словаре — *intervene*; в русско-азербайджанском словаре — *müdaxilə etmək.*

В НКРЯ:
Могли ли мы не итти на чрезвычайные меры при отсутствии хлебных резервов этак миллионов в 100 пудов, необходимых для того, чтобы выждать и **интервенировать** рынок, в смысле снижения цен на хлеб, или при отсутствии достаточных валютных резервов, необходимых для того, чтобы ввезти из-за границы большие партии хлеба? [И. В. Сталин. Об индустриализации и хлебной проблеме (1928)]

Современное употребление (нечастое, конечно, но есть):

> Если бы у нас были открыты рынки для иностранных заимствований, то в плавающий режим мы могли бы больше **интервенировать**, мы могли бы себе позволить сглаживать колебания ("Рейтер", 23.10.2015).
> Я надеюсь, что у нас ситуация не выйдет за границы, не будет повторена ситуация, когда иностранные войска **интервенировали** Украину ("Эхо Москвы", 04.12.2013).

Comment: Спасибо. Принял ваш ответ.

Answer (score 2):

У финансистов, в значении "вкладывать деньги" (в новые сферы, направления) - ***интервенировать***.

В других значениях - только "осуществлять интервенцию".

Вообще вне профжаргона существительные на "-енция", даже связанные по значению с каким-то действием (юриспруденция, индульгенция, каденция, деменция), синтетических ("однословных") глаголов не порождают.
Исключение знаю только одно: дивергенция - дивергировать, но тоже на грани профжаргона, если не за гранью.

Comment: behemothus то есть одно государство не может интервенировать другое, только осуществить интервенцию, иначе это будет выглядеть как терминология финансистов?

Comment: Ну да... Как-то так. Вернее сказать, это будет звучать как речевая ошибка.

Comment: @Третийглаз В книгах и словарях середины прошлого века глагол "интервенировать" в обсуждаемом значении употреблялся. Сейчас, вероятно, устарел.

Comment: @grizzly Да, даже у Ушакова есть. надо же... Я-то думал, что это можно представить разве что в речи галломанов времен "Войны и Мира", которые "по-русски плохо знали".

Comment: Поддержал ответ, но добавил бы ещё пару слов: конкуренция — конкурировать, интерференция — интерферировать, люминесценция — люминесцировать (последние из физики, но просачивается в широкий обиход).

Comment: @grizzly Да, про конкуренцию я что-то забыл. Про физические вещи судить мне трудно, я эти слова понимаю исключительно в физическом смысле.

Comment: @grizzly Благодарю! Важное уточнение, которое вполне подходит для полноценного ответа.